# What are the features in Snappy Ubuntu that make it more secure than the normal Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, server, security, ubuntu-core

I am thinking of using Snappy Ubuntu for IoT application. Security is important in IoT. What is the difference between Snappy Ubuntu and the normal Ubuntu that makes Snappy more secure compared to Ubuntu 14.04 desktop and server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a huge differences in security model of all Ubuntu versions. Indeed according to this [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/SnappyConfinement):

> Snappy confinement is an evolution of the security model for Ubuntu
>   Touch. The basic concepts for confined applications and the AppStore
>   model pertain to snappy applications as well. In short, applications
>   are confined by default through the use of various technologies and
>   this is achieved through a simple template-based system where policy
>   is extended through the use of caps (aka policy groups).

I think the most important will ran through the package system using click and the core itself, plus the filesystem capabilities.

I think you should read those:

- [ApplicationConfinement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/ApplicationConfinement)
- [SnappyConfinement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Specifications/SnappyConfinement)